# Обрывается создание массива

Tags: python

```py
razdelitel=['1','2','3','+','4','5','6','+','7','8','9']
chisla=''
li=[]
for symvol in razdelitel:
    if symvol=="1" or symvol=="2" or symvol=="3" or symvol=="4" or symvol=="5" or symvol=="6" or symvol=="7" or symvol=="8" or symvol=="9" or symvol=="0":
        chisla=chisla+symvol 
        continue
    else:
        li.append(int(chisla))
        chisla=''
        li.append(symvol)
        continue
    print(li)
```

Получается результат [123,'+',456,'+']
**Вопрос:** Куда пропало 789?

Comment: Лежат в переменной `chisla`, которую никто нигде в список `li` не запихнул.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно добавить после цикла проверку

```
if chisla:
    li.append(int(chisla))
```

Или воспользоваться встроенным средством группировки по признаку

```
import itertools

data = ['1', '2', '3', '+', '4', '5', '6', '+', '7', '8', '9']
out = []

for isnumber, group in itertools.groupby(data, key=str.isdigit):
    if isnumber:
        out.append(int(''.join(group)))
    else:
        out.extend(group)

print(out)
```

или

```
out = [x
       for isnumber, group in itertools.groupby(data, key=str.isdigit)
       for x in ([int(''.join(group))] if isnumber else group)]

print(out)
```